# structure of documents for versioning of a time series on mongodb

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, mongodb-query, database

I have a time series that grows and is (potentially) revised through time:

#### on "2013-01-01": First version of the data

"2013-01-01" 10

#### on "2013-01-02": Data of the 1st of Jan is revised from 10 to 11

"2013-01-01" 11

#### on "2013-02-01": First version of the data of the 1st of Feb

"2013-01-01" 11
"2013-02-01" 20

#### on "2013-02-02": Data of the 1st of Feb is revised from 20 to 21

"2013-01-01" 11
"2013-02-01" 21

## most frequent queries:

#### query1: get the most recent version of all dates

"2013-01-01" 11
"2013-02-01" 21

#### query2: get the time series as it was known at a certain date:

For instance, querying with "2013-02-01", I need to get
"2013-01-01" 11
"2013-02-01" 20

#### Note that query1 is a the same as query2 but with date = current date

I need help to structure my documents, and as I come from a relational background, I am not sure about the implications of my structure. I have basically identified 2 possible structure, and would be happy to have some feedbacks, or suggestions of other structure.

## OPTION A: Each revision in a separate document

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "date":"2013-01-01",
  "version_date":"2013-01-01",
  "value":10
}

{
  "id":"1",
  "date":"2013-01-01",
  "version_date":"2013-01-02",
  "value":11
}

{
  "id":"1",
  "date":"2013-02-01",
  "version_date":"2013-02-01",
  "value":20
}

{
  "id":"1",
  "date":"2013-02-01",
  "version_date":"2013-02-02",
  "value":21
}
```

## OPTION B: One document contains all the revisions of one date

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "date":"2013-01-01",
  "values" : [ 
              { "version_date":"2013-01-01",
                "value":10
              },
              {
                "version_date":"2013-01-02",
                "value":11
              }
}

{
  "id":"1",
  "date":"2013-02-01",
  "values" : [ 
              { "version_date":"2013-02-01",
                "value":20
              },
              {
                "version_date":"2013-02-02",
                "value":21
              }
}
```

In option B, I am also concerned by the fact that it might be a bit more difficult to perform the update query as the document has a growing part, which i am not sure is very well supported by / optimised for mongodb

EDIT: I am also considering option C to speed up query1: (although it might slow down a bit the writing)

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "date":"2013-01-01",
  "values" : [ 
              { "version_date":"2013-01-01",
                "value":10
              },
              {
                "version_date":"2013-01-02",
                "value":11
              }
  "last_value":11
}

{
  "id":"1",
  "date":"2013-02-01",
  "values" : [ 
              { "version_date":"2013-02-01",
                "value":20
              },
              {
                "version_date":"2013-02-02",
                "value":21
              }
  "last_value":21
}
```

Comment: interesting link http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/10/grid-pattern-managing-versioned-data.html

Answer (score 1):

As with all questions like this, you are the only person who can answer this. If you have your data - try both way do some benchmarking on real data with real queries and compare what is better. If you do not have data - try to simulate it.

Keep in mind that with option B and C you have to be aware of [16 Mb limit per document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size). So if you have a lot of versions - you might reach the limit (but you have to understand that a there should be too many versions to reach 16Mb). Also keep in mind that updating such documents can and up with many [moves on the disk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/).

Option B and C would be nice if you would need to select all revisions of a particular document at once, but I have not found this in your most often queries. Keep in mind that with right indexes you can achieve this as well with option A.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will keep in mind this limitation of 16Mb per document - should be fine in my case.    
Indeed the most frequent query is the other way round: get the entire time series for one version.

Comment: If this is the most frequent data, then option B/C might perform well. But I have to highlight it one more time: do benchmarking with your own data and only after this select a suitable option

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a very recent blog post on the official page covering this topic: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb
Take a look at that and ask any additional questions if required.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the above mentioned Options, and your requirements, it would be best to create your structure based on `date` , like you mentioned in Option-B.Also it would be nice if your `date` is indexed. Some scenarios (easy reads,updates) that show why this seems to be the proper optimized solution are:

1. Retrieving all the versions of a particular date.
2. Retrieve all versions of a certain period of time(that is range, e.g from jan 2012 to feb 2012)
3. Inserting a new version, you just have to use [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).
4. Removing an old version , just with a simple query using [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

Comment: ok, thank you for your answer. is it easy to perform query2: get the version of a certain date (ie: value for max version_date for all date)? Or do I have to get all and perform this subset in JSON in my own programing language

Comment: @RockScience , no logic in programming language is required, you just have to use [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/) correctly and it will be done.

Comment: @RockScience yes, just also refer [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) , it will be helpful for your structure.